# Literally impossible to create dynamic scrolling background in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, sprite-kit

I have been trying to create a simple scrolling ground node in my SK game for quite a few days now. The problem is, no matter what I try, I have little "gaps" in between each piece of the ground. Basically what I have right now is a method that is called, which takes the node and animates it by moving it across the screen with a certain duration (a variable called `gameSpeed`) and then on `completion` it runs a block that calls itself again. Every time though, I get these little tiny gaps, maybe 4 to 5 pixels wide, that seem to be the result of the method being called ~.02 seconds after it is completed.

I am not sure what to do. I have legitimately tried at least a few dozen workarounds. Before, I had worked around the problem by having a ground node that looked messy, and so I would have multiple methods calling the ground drawing method on staggered intervals, and there would never be any gaps. The overlaps weren't noticible because of the randomness of the ground. Unfortunately now that I have designed a ground node that I like the looks of, which has a discernible pattern, the "brute force" method of just shoving a bunch of nodes on top of each other to cover up the gaps will no longer work.

**On top of that, during the course of one ground node traveling the distance of the screen, the gamespeed changes about 2-3 times. I need the ground to be responsive to these changes with its movement.** Could anyone direct me towards a good solution?

Comment: Hi Todd, you will probably have to include some code snippets to help us make a better judgement of what might be causing your problem.  I have made a suggestion in an attempt to help you but I think your question could be improved upon.

Comment: typical problems are: 1) not moving the nodes synchronously - it's best not to run an action on each individual node but rather move one node and position the rest based on their offsets to the initial node. 2) cast node positions down to the nearest integer respectively pixel boundary (on Retina that means a .5 coordinate is on a pixel boundary). This prevents the "thin line gap" glitches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Node Gap Animation Problem**

1. Instead of attempting to animate each ground block individually would be to attach all ground blocks to a single root node.  This root node can then be moved and all child nodes will be moved by the same amount in a single call.
2. Another option would be to update the position of all your ground blocks during `SKScene` [update:](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/update:)

   Note that you would be setting the position of each ground block to where it should be in the next frame as apposed to animating the movement using an `SKAction`.

**Game Speed Change Problem**

If you are using `SKAction` to move your nodes then when ever the game speed changes you would need to call [removeAllActions:](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/removeAllActions) to remove all currently executing actions.  Alternatively you could call [removeActionForKey:](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/removeActionForKey:) to remove a specific action.

If you override `[SKScene update]` as I suggested in option 2 your nodes will move at the new game speed from the next frame after you change it.